# Detect duplicates

Tags: duplicates, stata

My question regards detecting duplicates.  Say I have the following data:

```
clear all
input str2 pos str10 name 
A Joe
A Joe
B Frank
C Mike
C Ted
D Mike
D Mike
E Bill
F Bill
end
```

If I want to detect all the duplicate names, I would simply type:

```
duplicates tag name, gen(flag)
```

This gives me:

```
pos name  flag
A   Joe   1
A   Joe   1
B   Frank 0
C   Mike  2
C   Ted   0
D   Mike  2
D   Mike  2
E   Bill  1
F   Bill  1
```

That is great - it indicates that `Joe`, `Mike`, and `Bill` are duplicates.

But let's say that I want to not include any duplicates that are duplicates only within `pos`.  In other words, I do not want to find that `Joe` is duplicate because Joe appears only within `pos` `A`.  I only want to find that `Mike` and `Bill` are duplicates.  (While `Mike` is duplicated within `D`, he also appears in `C`, so he appears in more than one `pos`.)

In other words, I want:

```
pos name  flag
A   Joe   0
A   Joe   0
B   Frank 0
C   Mike  1
C   Ted   0
D   Mike  1
D   Mike  1
E   Bill  1
F   Bill  1
```

Note that here `Mike` takes `flag` of only `1` instead of `2`.  That is because I am treating `Mike` in `D` as appearing only once instead of twice.  Having `2` instead of `1` is not problematic if the solution produces this.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer a duplicates problem in the specific sense of `duplicates`. (Disclaimer: I originally wrote it.)

You just want to know if a given name occurs in different groups. That problem is reviewed in various places, such as [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042).

One way to proceed is to tag each distinct joint occurrence of `name` and `pos` just once, and then count over groups.

```
clear 
input str1 pos str5 name  flag
A   Joe   1
A   Joe   1
B   Frank 0
C   Mike  2
C   Ted   0
D   Mike  2
D   Mike  2
E   Bill  1
F   Bill  1
end 
egen tag = tag(name pos) 
egen npos = total(tag), by(name) 
list , sepby(pos) 

     +---------------------------------+
     | pos    name   flag   tag   npos |
     |---------------------------------|
  1. |   A     Joe      1     1      1 |
  2. |   A     Joe      1     0      1 |
     |---------------------------------|
  3. |   B   Frank      0     1      1 |
     |---------------------------------|
  4. |   C    Mike      2     1      2 |
  5. |   C     Ted      0     1      1 |
     |---------------------------------|
  6. |   D    Mike      2     1      2 |
  7. |   D    Mike      2     0      2 |
     |---------------------------------|
  8. |   E    Bill      1     1      2 |
     |---------------------------------|
  9. |   F    Bill      1     1      2 |
     +---------------------------------+
```

Some may like to see a solution without `egen`:

```
bysort name pos: gen tag = _n == 1 
by name: gen npos = sum(tag) 
by name replace npos = npos[_N]
```

This could be rewritten using just one new variable:

```
bysort name pos: gen npos = _n == 1 
by name: replace npos = sum(npos) 
by name: replace npos = npos[_N]
```

Comment: Thanks!  Glad to get an answer from the world's expert on the subject.